# Asian language multisite IDN subdomain

Tags: multisite

Using an IDN internationalized domain name in Thai appears to work fine.  However when using WP Multisite Subdomain network and trying to ADD SITE as a SUBDOMAIN - it is not accepting the Thai characters and generates error "Missing or invalid site address."

I tried changing some setting in phpMyAdmin collation and wp-config.php but didn't really know what to do with that, and plugin intlWP which looked like it would do it, has not fixed the problem of using Thai as the subdomain site address.

this isn't a translation issue, it's a URL and WP Admin interface issue I think.

there has to be a way to have a WP multisite using Thai language subdomains... any suggestions welcome.  thanks

Comment: What if you use the address as [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#Example_of_IDNA_encoding)? (Firefox address bar shows IDN address in this format).

Comment: Its right; the core of WordPress have no possibility for this characters. I have change the core for this requirement for a customer. I will ask and check, how we have realized this and give feedback here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you dont need to edit core files.
Check this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-turkce/

This plugin letting "ŞşİıĞğÜüÖöÇç" (Turkish) characters  in permalinks, usernames and blog names. You need to define those 2 variable for usernames and blog names:

```
define( 'WPTURKCE_USER', true );
define( 'WPTURKCE_BLOG', true );
```